# fairseq installation requiring to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pytorch, apple-m1, fairseq

I'm trying to install fairseq, but this error keeps occurring.

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fairseq
```

which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

my environment:
Macbook Air 13' zsh M1 chip
Visual studio code 2

I tried these code:

```
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq
cd fairseq 
pip install --editable ./
```

and

```
CFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++" pip install --editable ./
```

Please help me. Thank you!